# Happy Thai videos?

Tags: resource-request, thai

Since there doesn't seem to be a Thai group, perhaps someone here is aware of something for Thai similar to "[Happy Chinese](https://youtube.com/watch?v=XIWFv4mkJGE)."  That's a series of fifteen minute videos that are somewhat entertaining and have some extremely basic language lessons mixed in.   The lessons are indeed very basic but the subtitles provide material for someone who is not a complete beginner.  I'm getting more entertainment than Chinese from it, but I am also trying to learn some Thai.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Learn Thai with Mod** ([Web site](http://learnthaiwithmod.com/), [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/ThaiwithMod)) seems to be a direct equivalent.

Note, these are **casual, unstructured lessons**. It may or may not appear useful, depending on the learner's approach of language learning.

Comment: I haven't actually watched any, but a perusal of the website suggests close enough for me to accept the answer.  Thanks!